# convert generic slice to channel

Tags: go, generics, channel

I would like to write a function that converts a slice into a channel.

This should be easy: Just create a channel and dump all the elements from the slice into it.

```golang
func slice_to_channel[T any](input_slice []T) chan T {
    var output_channel = chan T      // problem here
    for _, element := range input_slice {
        output_channel <- element
    }
    return output_channel
}
```

The problem is that I can't simply create this channel because I don't know it's type yet.

The code above fails to compile:

```
example.go:2:23: chan T (type) is not an expression
```

I also tried to leave out the generic type in the second line (`var output_channel = chan`). As expected, go would like us to specify the type.

```
example.go:2:23: syntax error: missing channel element type
```

How can I create a "channel of the same type as a give slice"?

Comment: Channels you have to _make_: `var output_channel = make(chan T)`. Note that you'll get a deadlock though: you can't send values on an unbuffered channel if no one is receiving from it. So you either have to use a buffered channel and/or a goroutine sending on it.